# How to set up custom fields in the registration widget?

Tags: php, facebook, registration

I am using the registration plugin from [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/#custom_fields) 
and I am setting up some custom fields in an `json_encode` array:

```
<?php
$fields = json_encode(array(
array('name' => 'name'),
array('name' => 'city', 'description' => 'City', 'type' => 'typeahead', 'categories'=>'city')
));
?>
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration.php?
         client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&
         redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Ftools%2Fecho%2F&
         fields=<?php echo urlencode($fields);?>"
    scrolling="auto"
    frameborder="no"
    style="border:none"
    allowTransparency="true"
    width="100%"
    height="330">
</iframe>
```

In the facebook example they say that you can set up something like this, and when you type it is gonna give you a hint with a `'city','country','state_province'`:

```
 {'name':'live',       'description':'Best Place to Live',       'type':'typeahead', 'categories':['city','country','state_province']}
```

In my case I try to do it like this:

```
array('name' => 'city', 'description' => 'City', 'type' => 'typeahead', 'categories'=>'city')
```

But it doesn't work. if i get that line out the plugin works just fine, which means I am not  setting it right.

I've also tried this, and it doesn't work:

```
array('name' => 'city', 'description' => 'City', 'type' => 'typeahead', 'categories':['city','country','state_province'])
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to do this:

```
array('name'=>'city', 'description'=>'City', 'type'=>'typeahead', 'categories'=>array('city', 'country', 'state_province'));
```

...instead. This:

```
'categories':['city','country','state_province']`
```

...is Javascript syntax and is not valid in PHP - it will result in a parse error. The equivalent in PHP is

```
'categories'=>array('city', 'country', 'state_province')
```